# How to convert char pointer into char in C Open VMS

Tags: c, ansi-c, vms

This is to convert from char pointer into char.

I followed the codes from another topic but it seems like it's not working to me.
I am using Open VMS Ansi C compiler for this. I don't know what's the difference with
another Platform.

```
main(){

char * field = "value1";
char c[100] = (char )field;

printf("c value is %s",&c);
```

}

the output of this is

```
c value is
```

which is unexpected for me I am expecting

```
c value is value1
```

hope you can help me.

Comment: hello thanks for your answers guys... it did work. 

But can I create my own function like for this scenario example conv_ptr_str function that converts pointer char to char;

say

        char *field = "value1";
        char c[100] = (char )field;
    
        char c = conv_ptr_str(field);
        
 
So that I could re use the resources or
this is the only way to convert things?

Answer (score 4):

```
strcpy(c, field);
```

You must be sure `c` has room for all the characters in `field`, including the NUL-terminator.  It does in this case, but in general, you will need an if check.

EDIT: In C, you can not return an array from a function.  If you need to allocate storage, but don't know the length, use `malloc`.  E.g.:

```
size_t size = strlen(field) + 1; //  If you don't know the source size.
char *c = malloc(size);
```

Then, use the same `strcpy` call as before.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

    char * field = "value";

    char c[100]="";
    strncpy(c,field,100);

    printf("c value is %s",c);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

In C, the `char` type holds a single character, not a string.  `char c[100];` doesn't allocate a `char` of length 100, it allocates an *array* of 100 consecutive `char`s, each one byte long, and that *array* can hold a string.

So what you seem to want to do is to fill an array of `char`s with the same `char` values that are at the location pointed at by a `char *`.  To do that, you can use `strncpy()` or any of several other functions:

```
strncpy(c,field,100); /* copy up to 100 chars from field to c */
c[99] = '\0';         /* ..and make sure the last char in c is '\0' */
```

..or use `strcpy()` since you know the string will fit in `c` (better in this case):

```
strcpy(c,field);
```

..or:

```
snprintf(c,100,"%s",field);
```

Comment: `strncpy()` is *not* just a safer version of `strcpy()` (as `snprintf()` is a safer version of `sprintf()`).  `strncpy()` can leave the target buffer unterminated (i.e., not containing a string), or can needlessly pad it with multiple `'\0'` characters when only one is necessary.  You're better off using `strcpy()` after confirming that the target buffer is big enough.

Comment: @KeithThompson The string is explicitly null-terminated in the example above. You do have a point about potentially padding extra null characters... though in cases where the source string's length isn't known calling `strlen()` before `strcpy()` isn't necessarily faster.